# Reading from a pin Arduino Uno (assembly)

Tags: atmel-studio

I am creating a project in which an Arduino reads (gets) a value from
a DHT sensor. The DHT sensor returns two values:

1. Temperature
2. Humidity

[image]

My assembly code:

```
sbi ddrd,5
cbi ddrd,2
sbi portd,5

start:

in r16,Pind2
cpi r16,80
brne On

jmp start

On:
cbi portd ,5
jmp start
```

After the code, the light remains turned on, but if the sensor sends '80' 
and I get it correctly it should be turned off.

Question: Am I Using the write way to read a pin?

Comment: The first thing I saw was a cartoon where apparently a schematic is supposed to be, so I quit before reading any of the text.

Comment: I'm not sure any of your code makes sense. Firstly you've got the roles of `pind` and `portd` backwards (port is for writing, pin is for reading). Secondly you haven't defined in your code what half of the stuff is (what is `ddrd`, what is `portd`, what is `Portd2`). Thirdly you are reading in the `portd` register (not an input), and then comparing it directly to a number (decimal 80, hex 0x50) - even if we assume you mean to read the inputs (`pind`), you haven't connected most of the pins on that port so who knows what value will return.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I am new to it can you plz write a simple code for me
which will receive data from DHT and Move it to a register? An Example Code?

Comment: This Tutorial shows how to read and write from complete Port
but I just need One Pin and Recieve Serial Data
http://www.avr-tutorials.com/digital/digital-input-output-assembly-programming-atmel-8-bits-avr-microcontrollers

Comment: `in r16, PIND`, assuming you are using avr-gcc. If you want just the bit 2, `andi r16, 1<<2`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about AVR assembly **NOT ARDUINO** and was properly asked on EESE, but **IMPROPERLY MIGRATED**.  The language **is not Aduino**, the pin specs **are AVR NOT ARDUINO** - the only thing "Arduino" about this is some soldermask masquerading as silkscreen on the board.

Comment: Yet another crap migration from @Nick Alexeev. Is there anything we can do about this?

Comment: Gentlemen, Nick Alexeev *asked me* if he could migrate this. Whilst the assembler question might be marginally off-topic, this is hardly an electronics question. The question specifically mentions an Arduino Uno. Personally I would be encouraging him to ditch assembler for such a simple task. It seems completely inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply reading the state of the input pin - this won't work.

Study the datasheet for the DHT22, available from Sparkfun or eslewhere.

To get data from the DTH22, you must first send a start signal, wait a specified time, then watch the level of the data line, measuring the time of each bit to determine whether it is a 1 or 0, and store the bits in five 8-bit variables.  You can then examine those variables to determine the temperature and humidity.

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for **writing** to an individual output bit:-

```
 sbi portd,5 ; make Port D output bit 5 high (set)

 cbi portd,5 ; make Port D output bit 5 low (clear)

 sbi pind,5  ; toggle Port D output bit 5 (low -> high, high -> low)
```

Instructions for **reading** an individual I/O pin:-

```
 sbis pind,2 ; skip next instruction if Port D pin 2 is high  

 sbic pind,2 ; skip next instruction if Port D pin 2 is low
```

Comment: Awsome, this answer is clear and answers the question really well.